# ember-cli call a makeBoundHelper function in javascript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-i18n

I have an ember-cli helper function: translate-i18n that I am nicely using in my hbs templates as an accessory helper to dockyards i18n translation library.

The helper I created takes the word as an argument and just provides for a few fallback situations (e.x. if a translation is missing, it will fire an airbrake error).

My helper is working fantastically when used within hbs templates, but it seems like it is impossible to call it from a JS file, specifically another helper file. In a nutshell, the problem is this:

- If I create the helper using `Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(translate);`
  the helper is not accessible using Ember.Handlebars.helpers .... so I can't call it that way. I CAN see that the helper exisits by doing this.container.lookup('helper:translate-i18n'), but I don't seem to have the ability to call the function this way.
- If I create the helper using register (instead of makeBound), so by doing this: `export default Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('translate', translate());`
  I can then access my helper from anywhere, but suddenly the container is not defined, and I no longer can get at the dockyards i18n (t helper), as this line throws an error: `var t = this.container.lookup('utils:t');`

Any suggestions/pointers/observations would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a handlebar helpers registered then you can access them from JS like

For eg : If you have a helper named '`doSomething`',

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('doSomething', function (args) {
 return something;
});
```

You can call the helper from JS like the below

```
Ember.Handlebars.helpers.doSomething(args);
```

Comment: this is true, and I did try this approach. But the 'doSomething' helper that you create in the above example won't have access to the container... it seems as if only makeBoundHelper gives you access to the container.

Comment: I will check that , But in the mean time it seems makeBoundHelper is deprecated.http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_makeBoundHelper